# How to pan google maps upon scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have this idea for an website where the background is made up of google maps.
As the user scrolls the map has to "move"/pan to a specific location. 
I've found a script that will set google maps as my background so this is not the issue.

Now my question is: how do I make the map "move"/pan depending on scroll position?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Animation or linked on where the user is browsing to on your Website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.panTo` method of the API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)  and call it from a scroll event

something like

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    // get current scroll position
    var currentScroll = $('element that scrolls').scrollTop();

    // calculate a new map point based on the currentScroll value
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(somelat, somelong);

    // pan to it
    map.panTo(latLng); // assuming map refers to the map object
});
```

Comment: Thanks A ton! I'm going to play with this :)